# How to format specific mail value in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I want to validate specific mail value with RegEx using vba.

Example: `aungkoko@desktopfromanoth.com`

User input email must exactly include `@desktopfromanoth.com`. Can I validate that with RegEx?

My code is here:

```
Private Function ValidateEmailAddress(ByRef strEmailAddress As String) As Boolean  
    Dim objRegExp As New RegExp

    objRegExp.IgnoreCase = True
    objRegExp.pattern = "^[\w-\.]+@([a-z]{16}+\.)+[A-Za-z]{2,3}$"
    ValidateEmailAddress = objRegExp.Test(strEmailAddress)
End Function
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following will validate for any email that ends with `@desktopfromanoth.com`

```
^[_a-z0-9-]+(.[a-z0-9-]+)@desktopfromanoth\.com$
```

For further information see [Email Address Regular Expression That 99.99% Works.](http://emailregex.com/)

If you want to match multiple email addresses use the following instead:

```
[_a-z0-9-]+(.[a-z0-9-]+)@desktopfromanoth\.com
```

See https://regex101.com/r/PjQKDx/1

Comment: It works bro.Thz so much.Your code is exactly what i want.Respect bro.

Comment: May I ask more.If i want to validate many emails like that with semicolon between then.Can i write like that? "^[_a-z0-9-]+(.[a-z0-9-]+)@desktopfromanoth.com$+([;.][_a-z0-9-]+(.[a-z0-9-]+)@desktopfromanoth.com$"

Comment: @MinKoKo First of all note that there was an error in my RegEx `desktopfromanoth.com` must be `desktopfromanoth\.com`. I added an alternative for multiple emails to my answer, have a look.

Answer (score 0):

Normally I use this one and it works in the most of cases:

```
^\w+@[a-zA-Z_]+?\.[a-zA-Z]{2,3}$
```

Comment: *"most of cases"* might not be enough. While eg `rübli.de` is a valid domain your regex doesn't recognize any emails like `example@rübli.de` as valid. • This might be of interest: [Email Address Regular Expression That 99.99% Works.](http://emailregex.com/)

Comment: I want user input email must exactly include @desktopfromanoth.com.Can i validate that with regex?

Comment: @Peh 100% agree. Misunderstood the fix part. Thanks for this useful link.