# how to format many emails with regex using vba

Tags: excel, vba

With vba, i want to validate many emails between then with semicolon,every mail must end with @customercurrency.com and user can put 2 or 3 or 4 or many emails as he want.
Example :  aung@customercurrency.com;thet@customercurrency.com;htoo@customercurrency.com
My code is here.But it might be something wrong.

```
Public Function ValidateEmailAddressWithSemi(ByRef strEmailAddress As String) As Boolean
    'Create Regular expression object
    Dim objRegExp As New RegExp

    'Set Case insensitive
    objRegExp.IgnoreCase = True
     objRegExp.pattern = "^\s?([_a-z0-9-]+(.[a-z0-9-]+)@customconcurrency.com)+([;.]([_a-z0-9-]+(.[a-z0-9-]+)@customconcurrency.com)*$"
    ValidateEmailAddress = objRegExp.Test(strEmailAddress)

End Function
```

Comment: I really need answers for this.Please help me if you can.

Comment: ercurrency vs concurrency

Comment: sry bro.I'll fix that

Comment: @MinKoKo have a look there: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54890036/3219613

Comment: It didn't work and show error like that value bro.Example : min@concurrency.com;thet@con.com

Answer (score 0):

try this pattern :

```
"^\s?([_a-z0-9-]+(.[a-z0-9-]+)@customercurrency.com)+([;.]([_a-z0-9-]+(.[a-z0-9-]+)@customercurrency.com))*$"
```

(mistake in the domain name and a paranthesis is missing)

Comment: It didn't work bro.I got answer with this code  ^([-a-z0-9~!$%^&*_=+}{\'?]+(\.[-a-z0-9~!$%^&*_=+}{\'?]+)*@(concurrency.com)[;]?)*$